# Is there a way to programmatically toggle 'freeway drive' on the ios simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I know theres the xcrun simctl command. but that only can help me launch the simulator and my app. how do I tell the simulator to toggle freeway drive from the command line/script?